# Why this is an invalid hql query?

Tags: grails, hql

I'm having a problem with this hql in a grails app:

this is the query

```
def books = Book.findAll("from book where author_id in (${listOfId?.join(',')}) and (owner_id is null or owner_id = ${ownerId}) and status = 'available'")
```

And this is the error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.GrailsQueryException: Invalid query [from coupon where campaign_id in (7) and (owner_id is null or owner_id = 1112) and status = 'available']
```

Any idea of why is this an invalid query? I'm looking for a hql validator with more info about what's the invalid part. No success for now

Thanks in advance

Comment: My wild guess is that list of 1 item might be invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your HQL query uses table and column names instead of using entities, fields and associations. You haven't shown your entities, but if they respect the usual conventions, the HQL query should look like

```
from Coupon c 
left join c.owner owner
where c.campaign.id in (7) 
and (owner.id is null or owner.id = 1112) 
and status = 'available'
```

You should also use parameterized queries instead of String concatenation. That makes your code less efficient, and subject to SQL injection attacks or simply escaping problems:

```
from Coupon c 
left join c.owner owner
where c.campaign.id in :campaignIdList 
and (owner.id is null or owner.id = :ownerId) 
and status = :status
```